# Set default python with pyenv

Tags: python, macos-catalina, pyenv

I am try to upgrade my Python version on my macOS Catalina 10.15.1 by install PYENV and PYPIP, and set global and local to version 3.8.0. but still when I try to python version it shows the python version which  built into the MacOS operating system. which part is missing?

```
$ pyenv -v
pyenv 1.2.14

$ pypip -v
zsh: command not found: pypip

$ pyenv versions
  system
* 3.8.0 (set by /Users/aj/.python-version)

$ pyenv global
3.8.0

$ pyenv local
3.8.0

$ python -V
Python 2.7.16
```

Comment: what's the output of `type -a python`?

Comment: $ type -a python
python is /usr/bin/python

Comment: that means your pyenv is not setup properly

Comment: what about the `python3 -V` command?  I think the `python` command defaults to python 2.x.x on some machines.  This is the case for me.

Comment: Re: edit -- see [Why not upload images of code or errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Answer (score 52):

For me OSX I had to put

```
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

inside my ~/.bashrc | ~/.zshrc

note that without the **--path** it didn't work

Comment: That fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thx! This helped me too. Switching from the old `pyenv init -` principle to `pyenv init --path` did the trick

Comment: Thank you, `--path` instead of `-` on ZSH worked

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. Just one correction for missing quote eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

Answer (score 18):

If the output of

```
type -a python
```

is  `/usr/bin/python`, and if there is no second line displayed, then pyenv is only setup partially.

You should have seem as **first** line something like

```
/home/username/.pyenv/shims/python
```

That means your pyenv is not setup properly. It is only set up partially.
What's missing is the pyenv shims which redirect to the correct version of python.

Probably your search path contains:
`/home/username/.pyenv/bin`, but it is missing `/home/username/.pyenv/shims`

(Following comments updated 2021-01-06):

Normally you should have three lines in your ~/.bashrc

The first two (or something equivalent), that you seem to have are:

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

On the other hand what you seem to be missing is a line, that looks like:

```
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

or a more elaborate but in most cases identical line:

```
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Try to add one of these missing lines to your .bashrc and see whether pyenv is working better.

You could also add  `~/.pyenv/shims/python` manually to your searchpath, but normally this should have been done by the `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` command

if `~/.pyenv/shims` is already in your search path, then check with

```
ls ~/.pyenv/shims
```

whether the directory exists and contains an executable named python.
Normally this should have been added latest after having done a `pyenv install 3.8.0`

**Addendum 2022-01-15:**

Please note that the way pyenv is initialized changed.
If you had an older pyenv version and you updated the cloned repository you have probably something like

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

in your `~/.bash_profile` (or your ~/.zshrc or ... depending on your shell)

This has to be changed to something lile

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: i had to do this in the .zshrc and it worked, i type echo $0 to find out if my terminal was using the bash_profile or .zshrc files

Comment: installed py2 in centos stream9 with pyenv but "python" still pointing to py3 after doing `pyenv shell 2`, after included your last line in my .zshrc (the line with the "--path"), it works like expected: python command opens a py2 version. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

In case you have multiple versions of python installed (you can use `pyenv versions` to see all the installed versions), you can set a particular one as `local` or `global` version:

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
* 2.7.18
* 3.7.8
  3.9.9

$ pyenv global 3.9.9

$ pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.18
  3.7.8
* 3.9.9
```

Answer (score 5):

As gelondia mentioned, you might need to add this code to your `~/.bash_profile` to get your `PATH` setup correctly:

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

`echo $PATH` should return something like `/Users/matthewpowers/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.  Notice that the `~/.pyenv/shims` directory is out front.

I added a separate answer because I think you should add some different code to your `~/.bash_profile` than what gelonida is suggesting.

This post used to contain valuable additional information that was removed by the mods for reasons I do not understand.

Answer (score 4):

Recently, this only works on macOS:

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
fi
```

Previously, I used `pyenv init -` only, which stopped doing its job at some point. But, if you want autocompletion just append both of them together, like this:

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Comment: .bash_profile or .zprofile or both need to be modified for this to work

Comment: This fixes it for me on Monterey. It shouldn't be this hard to update python version!? 1 hour wasted

Answer (score 2):

You can try running [pyenv-installer](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer) made by the same owners of pyenv. Running the script is as easy as

```sh
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

in MACOS, change the version in `~/.python-version` file to the installed version in the pyenv python version which one want to make global