# How to downgrade python version from 3.8 to 3.7 (mac)

Tags: python, virtualenv, okta, pipenv, python-3.8

I'm using Python & okta-aws tools and in order to fetch correct credentials on aws I need to run okta-aws init. But got an error message of `Could not read roles from Okta` and the system prompted that`"Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.7, but you are using 3.8.3 (/usr/local/Cellar/o/1.1.4/l/.venv/bin/python)`.

I've tried to search all the Pipfiles on the mac and it seems that the Pipflie under my `~/Pipfile` and `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.3_2/libexec/bin/Pipfile` all have the same python version of 3.8, while the Pipfile under my  `/usr/local/Cellar/okta-aws-tools/1.1.4/libexec/Pipfile` has `required python_version = 3.7`.

I've been struggling with this for a while and really not sure how I can fix this.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Consider installing `pyenv` with Homebrew on macOS

```
brew update
brew install pyenv
```

**OR** Clone the repository to get the latest version of `pyenv`

```
 git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
```

Define your environment variables
(*For a recent MacOS you may want to replace `~/.bash_profile` with `~/.zshrc` as that is the default shell*)

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Restart your shell so the path changes take effect

```
exec "$SHELL"
```

Verify the installation and check the available `python` versions

```
pyenv install --list
```

Install the required `python` version

```
pyenv install 3.7
```

Set it as your global version after installation

```
pyenv global 3.7
```

eval pyenv path

```
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

Verify your current `python` version the system is using

```
python3 --version
```

Comment: Also eval "$(pyenv init -)" to .bash_profile or .bashrc required. Then source .bashrc and reopened terminal is worked for me.

Comment: For newbies, you might clarify that you need to either brew install or git clone (but not both) depending on whether you need the latest version.

Comment: I just wanted to add that to finally set the pyenv global 3.7, you need to use the default macOS terminal. It doesn't work on the iTerm2.

Comment: @almas Dusal, can you be a bit more explicit what you mean by eval .... to ... using maybe command?.... got it it means add ```eval "$(pyenv init -)"``` to the .zshrc or .bashrc file

Comment: @Shayan it would be nice if you could add the pyenv init part into the answer.

Comment: Failing on M1 chip

Comment: I did all you suggested to downgrade from 3.9 to 3.8, but at the end python3 --version gives me python 3.9

Comment: I had to also do this for pyenv to work to downgrade from 3.9 to 3.7 https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/849#issuecomment-863456765

Comment: I had to add `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` in order to work

Comment: `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` used to work for me, and for somereason our IT installed some stuff on my mac os, now i have to use `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`

Comment: if you happen to have SDKMAN installed, be sure your command like below is not overriding or setting to a wrong path `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Thank you so much! for macOS Monterey replace ~/.bash_profile with ~/.zshrc

Comment: THIS IS GREAT!!! Just need to make sure eval ```"$(pyenv init --path)" ``` runs on terminal init

Answer (score 17):

I recommend you to install and use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), a Python Version Management.
Once intalled pyenv, install python 3.7:

```
pyenv install 3.7
```

And then set the environment `PYENV_VERSION` to version of python you want to use, on this case will be **3.7**:

```
pyenv shell 3.7
```

Comment: Great solution, on MacOS I had to use '3.7.13' for this to work.  '3.7' was no joy.

Answer (score 4):

brew only approach.

```
rm -rf $(brew --repository)/Library/Taps/company
brew tap-new company/team
brew extract python@3.7 company/team  --version=3.7.9 
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1  brew install company/team/python@3.7.9
brew link --force company/team/python@3.7.9
```

This creates a local tap, extracts python 3.7.X to a formula in that local tap and then installs and links that formula

The created local tap and the new formula file can be found in
`$(brew --repository)/Library/Taps/company/homebrew-team`

Answer (score -1):

- Reinstalled xcode-select (used solution [here](https://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/))
- Downgraded python 3.9 to 3.8.12 (used @Shayan's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62899833/14637536))
- Restarted terminal and checked default Python version, that's all

This is my solution for M1 Mac

Comment: How exactly did you "*Downgraded python 3.9 to 3.8.12*" and set it "*as global*"? Because that was the exact question, the OP was struggling to downgrade the Python used in the project from 3.8 to 3.7. So a more detailed set of steps would be useful.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Did you need to reinstall `xcode-select` in order for @Shayan's solution to work? If so, any idea why? I'm on an M1 Mac and the default Python version isn't updated even though both `pyenv`'s `global` and `shell` versions are set correctly after restarting the terminal.

Comment: I don't see how reinstalling xcode-select is relevant (I'm using an M1 Mac and it was already installed), but the only addition I have to @Shayan's solution to make it work is to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/69378384/2860309 and add `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` into the `.zshrc` file.