# Can't install alpaca_trade_api

Tags: python, pip

I tried using `pip install alpaca_trade_api` and it errored out with exit status 1.  I also tried `pip install alpaca-trade-api` and it had the same errors.

I get a ton of errors including this one:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/0b/qkyt93xx5ts8vf6lm8v7txxm0000gn/T/pip-install-ibu2qfpj/numpy_4257e6a256ca4130b766e6132889a532/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/0b/qkyt93xx5ts8vf6lm8v7txxm0000gn/T/pip-install-ibu2qfpj/numpy_4257e6a256ca4130b766e6132889a532/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/0b/qkyt93xx5ts8vf6lm8v7txxm0000gn/T/pip-record-w_zd6k6r/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/0b/qkyt93xx5ts8vf6lm8v7txxm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-ers_d9cp/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/0b/qkyt93xx5ts8vf6lm8v7txxm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-ers_d9cp/overlay/include/python3.8/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
```

Additionally the command takes forever to run.

I think this may have to do with me upgrading pip and pip3 and accidentally using sudo to upgrade and install them.

What can I do to fix this.

Comment: Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: Honestly not sure how to do this, but I'm trying to.

Comment: Full error traceback is over 60k lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue.  The issue was with installing pandas and numpy per [Pip install pandas results in error (Python3.8, Pycharm, Apple Silicon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825346/pip-install-pandas-results-in-error-python3-8-pycharm-apple-silicon)

To fix:

1. Install brew using

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. Install openblas followed by numpy and pandas using brew

```
brew install openblas
OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" pip install numpy pandas
```

3. Install alpaca trade api

```
pip install alpaca_trade_api
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ pip install alpaca-trade-api

Collecting alpaca-trade-api
      Downloading alpaca_trade_api-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
    Collecting urllib3<2,>1.24
      Downloading urllib3-1.26.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (153 kB)
         |████████████████████████████████| 153 kB 354 kB/s 
    Collecting websockets<9,>=8.0
      Downloading websockets-8.1.tar.gz (58 kB)
         |████████████████████████████████| 58 kB 345 kB/s 
    Collecting numpy
      Downloading numpy-1.20.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.4 MB)
         |████████████████████████████████| 15.4 MB 886 kB/s 
    Collecting msgpack==1.0.2
      Downloading msgpack-1.0.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (294 kB)
         |████████████████████████████████| 294 kB 4.3 MB/s 
    Collecting websocket-client<1,>=0.56.0
      Downloading websocket_client-0.59.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
         |████████████████████████████████| 67 kB 690 kB/s 
    Collecting pandas
      Downloading pandas-1.2.4-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (9.7 MB)
         |████████████████████████████████| 9.7 MB 4.5 MB/s 
    Collecting requests<3,>2
      Using cached requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
    Collecting six
      Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
    Collecting pytz>=2017.3
      Using cached pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
    Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7.3
      Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
    Collecting chardet<5,>=3.0.2
      Using cached chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
    Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
      Using cached certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
    Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
      Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
    Using legacy 'setup.py install' for websockets, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
    Installing collected packages: urllib3, websockets, numpy, msgpack, six, websocket-client, pytz, python-dateutil, pandas, chardet, certifi, idna, requests, alpaca-trade-api
        Running setup.py install for websockets ... done
    Successfully installed alpaca-trade-api-1.2.1 certifi-2020.12.5 chardet-4.0.0 idna-2.10 msgpack-1.0.2 numpy-1.20.2 pandas-1.2.4 python-
```

Comment: I tried this and I got the same errors.  Edited original post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

it still has some issues on `pip install alpaca-trade-api` in python 3.11. I just used google colab and installed it using `!pip install alpaca-trade-api` and it just worked pretty fine. Usually google colab has cleaner environment for installing new libraries when you have conflict.