# PYTHONPATH environment variable not saving on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, pythonpath

Running `echo $PYTHONPATH` returns a blank line:

```
freddy@dave ~ % echo $PYTHONPATH

freddy@dave ~ %
```

`echo $PATH` returns properly

```
freddy@dave ~ % echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin: ...
```

---

`.bash_profile` for user `freddy`:

```
# Fig pre block. Keep at the top of this file.
export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.local/bin"
eval "$(fig init bash pre)"

# Use Python 3.10, not homebrew
export PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10"

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:${PATH}"
source ~/.bash_profile

# Fig post block. Keep at the bottom of this file.
eval "$(fig init bash post)"%
```

---

Why does `echo $PYTHONPATH` return nothing? And how do I assign it to my Python3.10 path?

- I've tried restarting, this does not help
- I've run `source ~/.bash_profile` (this just closes the terminal after execution though?)
- A test variable: `export TEST="TEST"` also echos a blank line

As the comment suggests, I'm trying to use Python3.10 instead of my Homebrew installation, which is for some system packages

Comment: "(this just closes the terminal after execution though?)" - Do you have an ```exit``` in ```.bash_profile```? - Then remove it.

Comment: There is no `exit`. the entire file is shown above. Should i remove the `source ~/.bash_profile` from under `PATH` in the `bash_profile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `zsh`, not `bash`.

---

I moved `PYTHONPATH` to `.zshrc` and it saves as an environment variable now.

However, I have opted for the `pyenv` setup. And have added the following to my `.zshrc` file:

```
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/69378384/14141223